# Why does my UPS beep once then shut off my computer?

Tags: boot, power-supply

My computer is powered through a Meissner uninterruptible power supply plugged into the wall socket.

Four times in the last hour the UPS has beeped once, clicked, then the computer shut off instantly. I can then turn the computer back on and everything works fine.

My lights didn't flicker during this time, nor did I notice any effects on any other electronics not plugged into the UPS.

Does this mean my electricity supply at the wall is spiking? If so, isn't that exactly what my 'uninterruptible' device is supposed to prevent?

Else is the UPS failing? But then wouldn't it beep continuously?

What should I do?

Comment: The UPS batteries typically last about 4 years give or take.  When the battery is no longer usable, you will often get that behavior from the UPS.  If the UPS is more than 3 yrs old, that's a good bet.  Some UPSes are designed for easy battery access for replacement.  Some are a pain in the butt to open to replace the battery.  Replacement batteries are relatively inexpensive, especially if you get a third party battery (but stick with a reputable company and check reviews).

Comment: Is it possible for it not be the UPS? I'm thinking if it were the battery it would happen frequently. Not just a shutdown every few days.

Comment: You could be drawing more current through the UPS than it's able to cater for, so when you have a brown-out (the voltage into your property dips) the UPS isn't able to service the required amount of current draw. How much stuff do you have plugged into the UPS? And what model is the UPS? Do you have a desktop application to monitor the UPS battery, or view the UPS logs?

Comment: XT 700 powering one desktop PC and two screens. No monitoring app that I know off. But again, if it were drawing too much current wouldn't this problem be continuous?

Comment: It's possible that it's something else, but what you describe is typical behavior for a dead battery.  And if the unit is old, and the symptom is new, that's the first thing I would check.